# How to fetch sum of values across tables for time series data

Tags: mysql, database

I have sql data across multiple tables. Each table is a time stamp and value data table. I wish to fetch the sum of values across tables for different timestamps.

Not sure of path forward

Here is the data table creation sql code

```sql
--
-- Server version   5.6.28-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `table_name`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_name`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `avg` float NOT NULL,
  `min` float NOT NULL,
  `max` float NOT NULL,
  `tag_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table_name`
--

LOCK TABLES `table_name` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table_name` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES ('2019-06-01 10:43:53',10.5,8.2,12.5,'tag_1'),('2019-06-04 10:44:29',15.8,12.7,18,'tag_1'),('2019-06-08 10:45:23',9.4,6,11.5,'tag_1'),('2019-06-12 10:45:49',11,10,14,'tag_1'),('2019-06-24 10:46:15',24,17,25,'tag_1'),('2019-06-28 10:46:43',10.5,22.2,27.6,'tag_1'),('2019-06-01 10:43:53',105,82,125,'tag_2'),('2019-06-04 10:44:29',158,127,180,'tag_2'),('2019-06-08 10:45:23',94,60,115,'tag_2'),('2019-06-12 10:45:49',120,100,140,'tag_2'),('2019-06-24 10:46:15',240,170,250,'tag_2'),('2019-06-28 10:46:43',249,222,276,'tag_2');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

for example, the objective will to fetch avg value of tag_1 + tag_2 (sum) at timestamp '2019-06-01 10:43:53'

one further question. How to handle other arithmetic operations. e.g. if i wish to fetch avg of (tag_1 - tag_2) or (tag_1 * 1000 - tag_2)?

Comment: Which programing languages are you using?

Comment: You wont be able to get an average, all you will get is an average of the averages, unless you also have a count for each data point.

Comment: You cannot insert the same value for the unique key column. In your case, you are inserting the same timestamp. With this, you get only 1 row per timestamp. Edit your question with working data and expected end result.

Comment: Why is this tagged sql-server when your DDL is mysql-specific?

Comment: @Yeou thank you, and sorry for the mistake

Comment: @AlirezaA2F MySQL

Comment: @Shawn corrected tags to mySQL. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared UNIQUE KEY on column `timestamp` but providing values '2019-06-01 10:43:53' twice to insert into the table. If I guess this UNIQUE KEY setup is unintentional and the column can hold duplicate value, We can go forward to calculate Average of column avg,min & max as below by applying GROUP BY on column `timestamp`.

Note: Workable for both MySQL and MSSQL.

```
SELECT timestamp,
round(avg(avg),2) avg_avg,
round(avg(min),2) avg_min,
round(avg(max),2) avg_max 
FROM test_sum_table
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY 1
```

For further arithmetic operation, you can customize the query as below. I have added 2 sample arithmetic operation to it but you can add any other as per requirement.

```
SELECT 
timestamp,
Tag_1_Avg-Tag_2_Avg,
Tag_1_Avg*1000-Tag_2_Avg
FROM
(
    SELECT timestamp,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'tag_1' THEN avg ELSE 0 END),2) Tag_1_Avg,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'tag_2' THEN avg ELSE 0 END),2) Tag_2_Avg,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'tag_1' THEN min ELSE 0 END),2) Tag_1_min,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'tag_2' THEN min ELSE 0 END),2) Tag_2_min,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'tag_1' THEN max ELSE 0 END),2) Tag_1_max,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'tag_2' THEN max ELSE 0 END),2) Tag_2_max
    FROM test_sum_table
    group by timestamp
)A
```

Comment: thanks. This works! one further question. How to handle other arithmetic operations. e.g. if i wish to fetch avg of (tag_1 - tag_2) or (tag_1 * 1000 - tag_2)?

Comment: On the actual DB, there are many records, and to optimize the query, I added a where clause. Works like a Charm!